# Exception Unhandled while trying to initialize dynamic array

Tags: c++, oop, memory

I'm allocating dynamic memory in my class as a private: variable

Then in the constructor I'm trying to initialize the array.

```
public
Display(int Width, int Height) {
    nScreenHeight = Height;
    nScreenWidth = Width;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight); i++) screen[i] = L'';
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
}

private:
    int nScreenWidth;
    int nScreenHeight;
    wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight];
```

If I try run the program an Exception Unhanded in thrown.

Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.
this->screen was 0x2096112.

While trying to initialize the buffer screen with L' '

Comment: `wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight];` nScreenHeight and nScreenWidth are not initailized when this executes. Initialize `screen` in your constructor.

Comment: `wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight];` doesn't do what you think it does. I wonder if this even compiles. Put `screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight]` to your constructor initializer list at least.

Comment: Unrelated, out of curiosity, what does `L''` actually evaluate as? I'm surprised that even compiles.

Comment: It is type LPCWSTR simply trying to clear the buffer with empty spaces. But indeed I was messing up what is where.

Comment: @WhozCraig I know, right?  I was expecting `L""`, (a pointer to a null-terminated wchar_t string) not `L''` .  `L''` should result in a compiler error: `error: empty character constant`.

Comment: Should probably have written `screen[i] = '\0'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memebers are initialized in the order they appear in the class declaration before the body of the constructor is executed. So what happens is:

- `nScreenWidth` is default initialized (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization))
- `nScreenHeight` is default initialized
- `screen` is initialized with `new wchar_t[nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight]`
- only now the constructor runs and you assign values to `nScreenWidth` and `nScreenHeight`

Use the initializer list for all members to avoid confusion:

```
Display(int Width, int Height) : 
   nScreenWidth(Width), nScreenHeight(Height), screen(new wchar_t[nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight])
{
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight); i++) screen[i] = L'';
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
}
```

Even better would be to use a `std::vector<wchar_t>`, the constructor would be

```
Display(int Width, int Height) : 
       nScreenWidth(Width), nScreenHeight(Height), screen(Width*Height)
{
    ...
```

and instead of bothering about the [rule of three/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) you can rely on the rule of zero.

Comment: @WhozCraig cannot believe I missed a chance to promote `std::vector` ;)

Comment: @ formerlyknownas_463035818 as you mentioned that members are initialized in order they appear in class and after that constructor runs so could not understand why exception occurred ?

Comment: @Kapil oh i didnt mention it explicitly. Look at my bulletpoints again, when you initialize the vector you initialize it with 0 size, because only later you assign the passed size to the members. Then when you try to access elements of the array you go out of bounds